# Flutter RichText clickable date / time user-generated text parsing

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime

I would like to have WhatsApp-like clickable date/time segments for user-generated text blocks:
[image: WhatsApp date highlighted, underscored and clickable]

As you can see, dates in message boxes on WhatsApp become clickable. The way I see it implemented is simply regex-ing through every message to replace such dates with TextSpans that have the gesture recognizer property and formatting set. With that said, complexity comes with having multiple languages and different date & time formats.

Matching 00/00/0000 date formats is going to be easy, but here's a list of e.g. problematic text inputs:

- I'll see you in **3 days** (number of days)
- Let's meet on **Friday** (the next *day)
- Call me **at 3** (the nearest 3am/3pm)
- Wir sehen uns in **3 Tagen** (different language)
- ...

Is there a Dart library that could handle all these complex cases out of the box, similar to e.g. JavaScript's [chrono](https://github.com/wanasit/chrono)?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any ready-to-use solutions and ended up porting a popular Chrono JS library over to Dart – only in english for now though.

Here's the pub.dev link: https://pub.dev/packages/chrono_dart

It finds any dates and date-related phrases in human-generated text and returns them as objects containing `DateTime`. Example use:

```dart
import 'package:chrono_dart/chrono_dart.dart' as chrono;

chrono.parse('An appointment on Sep 12');
/* [<ParsedResult>{ 
    index: 18,
    text: 'Sep 12',
    date() => DateTime('2023-09-12T12:00:00'),
    start: ...
}] */
```